# How to list All android apps/packages?

Tags: android, kotlin

Good morning,

I'm looking for a solution to list all android packages/apps using Android studio - kotlin. I know that in the past, methods such as `getInstalledApplications`, `getInstalledPackages` or `queryIntentActivitiesAsUser` were used for this task but these are now deprecated in the latest Android API versions.
I also tried to read the `/data/system/packages.xml` file to extract all the com* packages but I think it is a violation of Android security. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

I tried this method but it did not work since `getInstalledApplications` is no more supported.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Log.d("TAG", "Source dir : " + packageInfo.sourceDir);
    Log.d("TAG", "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the other method (with an object instead of an integer flag) is not deprecated [PackageManager#getInstalledApplications](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstalledApplications(android.content.pm.PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags))

Have you tried to use the method?

I think you can try something like

```
packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can something like this helps you ? :

```
val pm: PackageManager = context.packageManager
val packages: List<PackageInfo> = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.MATCH_ALL)

for (packageInfo in packages) {
    Log.d("PackageList", packageInfo.packageName)
}
```

Edit 1: getInstalledPackages is deprecaded, you need to use : getInstalledPackages(int flags)

Edit 2: it's deprecated too so let's use getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.MATCH_ALL)

Comment: Unfortunately it is the same problem. Maybe I'm not following you or it is an error but you suggest to use `getInstalledPackages(int flags)`

Comment: If you use getInstalledPackages(int flags) which is not deprecated, what do you have ?

Comment: this method is deprecated too, I got nothing

Comment: So let's try : getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.MATCH_ALL), I updated my answer please tell me if it's better